# Django : Update the categories (selected by Select Field) of all checked products at once

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is my Views.

```
@ login_required
def product_list(request):
    products = ProductBasicModels.objects.filter(whose=request.user).prefetch_related('category', 'category__category').order_by('category__ordering_num')
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'medicalapp_1/products_h.html', context)


@ login_required
def product_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(ProductBasicModels, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.whose = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('product_list')
    else:
        form = ProductForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'medicalapp_1/product_add.html', {'form': form})
```

and my Models

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ordering_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering_num']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductBasicModels(models.Model):
    whose = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check = models.BooleanField(default=False) # this is for Checkbox.
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Change this with Checkbox
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    standard = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    outbox = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    orderto = models.ForeignKey(OrderCompany, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Forms

```
class ProductForm(forms. ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductBasicModels
        fields = ('check', 'category', 'name', 'standard', 'maker', 'outbox', 'extra', 'orderto')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

and my Template..

```
<tbody>
{% for product in subcat.list %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-block">
                <input type="checkbox" name="product_selected" value="{{product.id}}" />
            </label>

        </td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.standard }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.maker }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.outbox }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.extra }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ product.orderto }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="{% url 'product_edit' pk=product.pk %}"
               class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"> EDIT</i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="{% url 'product_del' pk=product.pk %}"
               class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-outline">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Im doing as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

What I need to do is to change the category all of Checked (Red Color in the Image) Products(CheckBox) at once..
How to make funtions with that list of checked?
Always thank you for your help.
and Im sorry for only question without enough studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form with product_selected checkboxes and category that must be set. On form submit(in your product_list view POST handler code), you can update all selected categories this way:

In your template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'products:list' %}">
    {{ products_form.category }}
    <input type="submit" name="update_products" value="Save">
    ...
    <tbody>
    {% for product in subcat.list %}
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline btn-block">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="product_selected" value="{{product.id}}" />
                </label>
    ...
</from>
```

Add a new form:

```
class ProductsUpdateForm(forms. Form):
    product_selected = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
    category = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        products = kwargs.pop('products', [])
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # TODO: you need to set your allowed category choices
        # self.fields['category'].choices = get_allowed_categories()
        self.fields['product_selected'].choices = [(product.id, product.id) for product in products]
```

In your view validate form and update products:

```
@ login_required
def product_list(request):
    products = ProductBasicModels.objects.filter(whose=request.user).prefetch_related('category', 'category__category').order_by('category__ordering_num')

    products_form = ProductsUpdateForm(request.POST or None, products=products)
    if 'update_products' in request.POST:
        if products_form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            ProductBasicModels.objects.filter(
                id__in=data['product_selected']
            ).update(category_id=data['category'])

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'products_form': products_form
    }

    return render(request, 'medicalapp_1/products_h.html', context)
```

Note that this is not a fully working code, but an example of how you can implement it.

Comment: I'm sorry Im very Newbie of Django. So I cannot understand perfactly your advice.. btw, I've just created NewFrom which has 'check' and 'category' and 'name' fields. than could you explain more detail about writing view in the product_list view?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you the concept, hope it will help you